# Extracting numbers only from cells with mixed values

Tags: r

I have been searching for an answer for a long time and can't find one.  I have a column of data such as:

```
22 apples, 16 oranges
13 plums, 22 large green grapes
52 fig leaves, 2 peanuts
```

I need to extract just the numbers for each cell, and add them and put that in a new column.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean you have a column of data? Like these are all values in the same column of a table?

Comment: You probably need to look at regular expressions. ?regex

Comment: yes, each cell in the column contains both numbers and words.  I just need the total of the numbers, put into a new column.  So a cell might contain 22 apples, 16 oranges.  I want 38 in a new cell.

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Your question is unclear, and it lacks a reproducible example.  In order for people to give you the best help, we need a clear statement of the problem, code to reproduce your data, your attempts to solve the problem yourself, and the desired result.  See [ask], [mcve], and [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: please edit your question to indicate that `c(38,35,54)` would be the correct result for this example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input <- "22 apples, 16 oranges
13 plums, 22 large green grapes
52 fig leaves, 2 peanuts"

table <- read.table(text=input, sep=",", col.names=c("first", "second"))

Strip <- function(x)
  gsub("^[ ]*|[ ]*$", "", x)

Getnumber <- function(x, pattern="^([0-9]+) (.+)$")
  as.numeric(sub(pattern, "\\1", Strip(x)))

table$sum <- Getnumber(table$first) + Getnumber(table$second)
```

Then you get:

```
> table

          first                 second sum
1     22 apples             16 oranges  38
2      13 plums  22 large green grapes  35
3 52 fig leaves              2 peanuts  54

> table$sum
[1] 38 35 54
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this without looping over the columns by using a character matrix for extraction and then switching its mode to numeric after that.  Using @crippledlambda's data `table`, we have

```
m <- gsub("\\D+", "", as.matrix(table))
mode(m) <- "numeric"
rowSums(m)
# [1] 38 35 54
```

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone.  Its been hard for an old chemist to suddenly get dropped into the middle of a programming pool!

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c("22 apples, 16 oranges",
       "13 plums, 22 large green grapes",
       "52 fig leaves, 2 peanuts")
```

Although this can also be done with base R (e.g. `gsub` followed by `strsplit`), `stringr::str_extract_all` is convenient.

```
library(stringr)
numstr <- str_extract_all(x,"[0-9]+")
```

Now convert strings to numeric and combine ...

```
sapply(numstr,
       function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
```